# Setting up ubuntu to send mail from PHPMailer

Tags: ubuntu, php, smtp, sendmail, ubuntu-14.04

I have a small server, inside the company where I work, which has an app that needs to send email to notify users for different reasons.

I'm using PHPMailer to do this. But as I suspected, I need to configure something. And by something I mean probably an SMPT or iMAP or I don't really know what to do. Anyone knows what can I do to send mail with PHPMailer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You guess right, you have to configure something as stated in the [Readme](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/README.md) :

> The PHP mail() function usually sends via a local mail server,
>   typically fronted by a `sendmail` binary on Linux, BSD and OS X
>   platforms

You should install and configure `sendmail`, but how to do this would be a full other question.

However you could [find this interesting](http://developernote.com/2012/07/how-i-configured-sendmail-for-php-on-ubuntu-server-12-04/).